# Synchronizing with the Olson TZ database

Tags: php, time, synchronization, timezone

I'm designing a calendar application

I figured out that to work correctly with at least future events, I need the data in the Olson db.
I also figured out that I want to store it in my own db table, and synchronize this table  with the Olson db periodically.

What would be a good approach for this synchronization?

- Anybody aware of a ready component for converting the Olson text files into a db table?
- I heard about this data being already embedded in some way into unix systems. Is this true? Is there an easy way to get the data from unix to the DB?
- Will using the "compiled" version of the Olson files be helpful?
- any other ideas are wellcome

We are working with php, Yii, mysql

(I'm aware of the [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices) thread, and many other related questions, but didn't find an answer to this particular question)

Answer (score 0):

[This blog entry](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2011/08/31/zend-ical-a-long-term-journey) is about creating an iCalendar component for the Zend Framework.  When it came to Time Zone definitions, his solution was to use the [Olson TZ database](ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/) together with [vzic](http://code.google.com/p/tzurl/), which converts the Olson timezones to iCalendar timezones.